# Facebook App Approval (Simulated iOS Build)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ios-simulator

I'm trying to get my app approved by Facebook to use the publish_actions permission. They require you to upload a version of your app to their site in order to complete their review process.

They provide this tutorial for doing so : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/#generate-simulator.

However, since I am building a workspace, this tutorial is not exactly appropriate. Using

xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 -workspace  -scheme

instead of their provided xcodebuild command builds my app successfully.

And all is well. However, they can't open the file created through this method. I am able to open the file locally using ios-sim (https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim). AFAIK, the standard iPhone Simulator cannot be used to open these since Xcode 5 (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So, does anyone know what method Facebook uses to open and run your simulated iOS builds? (So that I can test my builds against their process before waiting days for them to respond). Or does anyone see a problem with the way I am building above?

Comment: What doesn't work about the provided xcodebuild command in the docs?

Comment: I am building a workspace, instead of just a project.

Comment: The important thing is that you get a built copy of the app targeted to the simulator and i386 architecture - the example assumes a relatively simple project but if yours is more complicated the same basic instructions should work, except that you may need to change which build command is needed to build the app

Comment: Great. How do I verify that what I've created is going to work for you guys?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what command replicates what the review team will be doing, but if it loads in your own simulator that's likely a good sign

Comment: I am in the face of build the package and i am also having a workspace. I tried to use the snippet above but i get an error saying that i should specify the scheme. I don't have any idea what a scheme is. Can anybody type the full command?

Comment: @user3618120 I am using CocoaPods so it is pretty much a workspace... did you find out how to get this working? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the command like that:

```
xcodebuild  -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 -workspace MYPROJECTNAME.xcworkspace -scheme "MYPROJECTNAME Development" -configuration "MYPROJECTNAME Development" -derivedDataPath ../buildd
```

where MYPROJECTNAME was the name of the project.

So except specifying the configuration if you have more than one, your build command seems ok.

I am sending the build these days and I will tell you the result.

PS.1 It is a good idea to put the command you use in the "Review instructions" field just to make sure they know that you have workspace instead of single project.

PS.2 Do they say what was the error?